# Excel 2010 Filter by string to prevent them being deleted by remove duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a list and sometimes there are duplicated things that normally get removed with remove duplicates no problem. This time I found I have a common used string and don't want any of these strings to get deleted in case they are have the same amount. the code goes like

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rw As Long

Rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Set Rng = Range("A3:K" & Rw)
With Rng
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Discount*", Operator:=xlAnd
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$1000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

This code hides "Discount" but when it removes duplicates it skips the filter and deletes them anyways. from the data shown to excel they are exactly the same but the data comes from QuickBooks and I need all the discounts to make everything add up properly.

Comment: Can you sort the data putting the discounts at the end, set your range to exclude them, remove duplicates, then re-sort to the original sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method:

Sort the data putting Discounts at the beginning or end.

Filter the data hiding the Discounts.

Use `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` to select everything NOT 
a discount.

Remove duplicates from the selected range.

Remove duplicates and Sort do not work on multiple ranges so getting the discounts in one block and not selecting them is important.